# Use of "de" before some complements

Tags: grammaire, adjectifs

Here is an example of the use of "de" preceding the complement of the verb être (a copular verb):

"Elle est quelqu'un de très passionné."

The interjected "de" and the ungendered "passionné" suggest that "passionné" is not really an adjective attached to "elle". But what is it? Would "Elle est quelqu'un très passionnée" be correct, or would one need to say "Elle est très passionnée"? And do the same rules apply irrespective of the verb (for example, "devenir", "sembler", "trouver" and other copular verbs)?

Answer (score 1):

- Here is an example of the use of "de" preceding the complement of the verb être

  *De* is not preceding the complement of the verb but is in the middle of it.

  > ...*quelqu'un **de** très passionné*. (someone very passionate)
- The interjected "de" and the ungendered "passionné" suggest that "passionné" is not really an adjective attached to "elle". But what is it?

  Correct, *passionné* is an adjective attached to *quelqu'un*.
- Would "Elle est quelqu'un très passionnée" be correct, or would one need to say "Elle est très passionnée"?

  *Quelqu'un très passionné* doesn't work, the preposition *de* is mandatory after *quelqu'un* if something qualifying it follows.
  This is true for other indefinite pronouns like *quelque chose*, *rien*, and *personne*. e.g.

  > *Je cherche quelque chose **de** reposant pour les vacances.*
  >
  > *Je ne trouve rien **de** bon dans ce restaurant.*
  >
  > *Il n'y a personne **de** disponible aujourd'hui.*

  If a verb follows, you use *qui*:

  > *Je cherche quelqu'un **qui** pourrais me conduire à la gare.*
  >
  > *C'est quelque chose **qui** fait envie.*
  >
  > *Il n'y a rien ni personne **qui** m'inspire.*

  Your alternate proposition is fine:
  ,

  > *Elle est très passionnée*
- And do the same rules apply irrespective of the verb (for example, "devenir", "sembler", "trouver" and other copular verbs)?

  Yes. It's unrelated to the verb. *Quelqu'un* is masculine, regardless of who it refers to, so the adjective must agree with it.

  > *J'ai découvert dans cette femme quelqu'un de très **passionné**.*

  However, if you use *qui*, this constraint is relaxed:

  > *J'ai découvert dans cette femme quelqu'un qui sait ce qu'**elle** veut.*

  See [A la fortune du mot - 14/12/2013 - Bruno Dewaele](http://alafortunedumot.blogs.lavoixdunord.fr/archive/2013/12/14/100-12480.html)

  Note that *quelqu'une* is very rare but does exist so you might venture *Elle est quelqu'une de très passionnée* as a potential still very risky alternative.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I suppose it would be useless to ask why de is needed with quelqu'un.

Comment: I used the word "interjected" not in its grammatical sense but in its more general meaning of "put [thrown] between".

Comment: Answer edited to provide some information about this *de*.

Comment: Thank you! Is there some strange (historical?) reason why _de_ has to be used with _quelqu'un_?

Comment: It must be an ancient thing. Italian has the same *de* in *qualcuno di stupido* (*quelqu'un de stupide* / "someone stupid") and *qualcosa di buono*  (*quelque chose de bon* / "something good"). There is no such *de* in Spanish though (*alguien stupido/algo bueno*)

Comment: "This is true for other indefinite pronouns like quelque chose, rien, and personne." Are there others? I note that "certain", for example, is not one.

Comment: *Il n'y en a aucun de très passionné*, *Il n'y en a pas un de très passionné*, *Il y en a certains de très passionnés*, *Il y en a plusieurs de très passionnés.*

Comment: @jilliagre: Merci !